# Synology NAS DSM: SSH client to backup/rsync a REMOTE server locally

Tags: ssh, backup, nas, rsync, synology-diskstation

Scenario:

- a remote Linux webserver (Ubuntu 22.04)
- a local Synology DS220+ with DSM 7.1

I would like to use the Synology to access the remote server via SSH to rsync the server data locally. The Synology would then create a local copy of the remote server data. Please note: the Synology would be the SSH CLIENT here, not the other way around.

The procedure needs to be scheduled, to run it automatically.

I haven't tried anything yet because I don't even know where to start. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I contacted Synology Support about this. They pointed me to "[Active Backup for Business](https://www.synology.com/en-global/dsm/feature/active-backup-business/overview)", which works exactly as I needed

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that it is set up to allow that to happen.  The Synology reference for how to do rsync backups is [**here**](https://kb.synology.com/en-us/DSM/tutorial/How_to_back_up_Linux_computer_to_Synology_NAS).

There is no suggestion of any possibility of doing the backup in the reverse direction, even though rsync allows that mode.

However, if you can log in as root on the Synology device with a proper bash shell (verify whether the embedded OS used by the device is linux), and if the device allows "at" jobs or "cron" jobs to be scheduled, then you can write a script to perform that.

If, however, you are looking for a script that does backups using rsync (in general), then let me know and I can add 2 very different scripts, from which you can distill any functions/processes you would prefer to use.